# Write json to file as text Elixir

Tags: json, elixir

I have done the following is there a better way to do this?:

```
File.write("../hello", Poison.encode!(some_stuff))
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything wrong with what you have. Looks fine to me. Is there something bothering you about this method of writing to a file?

Comment: Define "better"?  Better in what sense?  Simpler?  I doubt you'll find simpler code. Faster?  Perhaps but unless you're talking about algorithmic complexity (Big-O that is) it's unlikely to be significantly faster in all cases. Less code?  Again I doubt you'll find a smaller example of code than this.  Maybe you should spell out what you find lacking in your solution?

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I meant better in the most generic sense. Thank you for elaborating in your comment. I was having difficulties finding an answer, and when I did, I was unsure if there was a "better" solution.

Comment: I am not sure if you're new to software development or not but "most generic"  is not often useful in discussing code.  Details are important when discussing code and questions about code.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**You are missing the third argument**, the mode options. Something like this would work:

```
File.write("../hello", Poison.encode!(some_stuff), [:binary])
```

Other than the missing argument, **what you have is a line of code that easy to understand**. With your use of `encode!` an exception will be raised if the encoding fails. If you want to ensure the file is written successfully without checking the return value from `File.write/3` you should use `File.write!/3`. Using `File.write!/3` fits better with Erlang's "let it crash" philosophy (http://learnyousomeerlang.com/errors-and-exceptions). Though it all depends on the context of this line...

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I was using it directly in the repl to do some debugging. So was interested in whether the encoding was working or not.